# Variable in UPDATE oracle in procedure : invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I don't understand why service is complaining with 
Fehler(36,11): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "FOUND_VP": invalid identifier

Variable is declared in the first begin... 
Is it not possible to use variable directly in queries ?

when trying store following procedure :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE fpwl_update_vp(
     my_zn IN NUMBER, my_verwaltung IN VARCHAR2 , my_variante IN NUMBER, my_vp IN NUMBER 
   ) IS



BEGIN

DECLARE
search_VP IFT_INFO_LAUF.VP%TYPE;
found_VP IFT_INFO_LAUF.VP%TYPE;
INFOversion number := 25;


BEGIN -- search SYFA_VP

          SELECT SYFA_VP
          INTO found_VP
          FROM FPWL_VP_MAPPING
          WHERE INFO_VP=search_VP ;


          exception
          when no_data_found then
           dbms_output.put_line ('Kein SYFA VP : Importiere aus SYFA');
          --found_VP:=:=cus_info25.pa_info_data.fn_insert_syfa_vp(my_vp,25);

          WHEN OTHERS THEN
          ROLLBACK;
          RETURN;
END; -- SYFA VP


-- Update VP
UPDATE IFT_INFO_LAUF
 SET vp = found_VP
WHERE id_kopf IN 
  (SELECT id_kopf 
    FROM ift_info_kopf 
    WHERE fahrtnummer= my_zn  
    AND verwaltung= my_verwaltung
    AND variante = my_variante
  )
;


  --COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;

END ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that found_VP is going out of scope.

Move the contents of the "DECLARE" block to just after the "IS":

```
create or replace PROCEDURE fpwl_update_vp(
 my_zn IN NUMBER, my_verwaltung IN VARCHAR2 , my_variante IN NUMBER, my_vp IN NUMBER 
) IS
  search_VP IFT_INFO_LAUF.VP%TYPE;
  found_VP IFT_INFO_LAUF.VP%TYPE;
  INFOversion number := 25;
BEGIN
  BEGIN -- search SYFA_VP

  etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

```
FPWL_VP_MAPPING.SYFA_VP
```

is the same **type** with

```
IFT_INFO_LAUF.VP
```

and make sure that

```
SELECT SYFA_VP INTO found_VP FROM FPWL_VP_MAPPING WHERE INFO_VP=search_VP ;
```

does not return multiple rows.
But I doubt that is the case with the error that you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message refers to line 36 and the reference to `found_VP` in your code sample is on line 18, you've omitted the part of the code that actually has the problem.

It looks like you have a scope problem; you're declaring `found_VP` in an inner block (one level of `DECLARE`/`BEGIN`/`END`) and referring to it outside that block, either in the parent block or another one at the same level. The issue isn't where you're selecting into `found_VP`, it's (I think) that you're referring to it again later on, beyond the code you've posted, and therefore outside the block the variable is declared in.

To demonstrate, I'll declare `l_name` in an inner block, as you seem to have done:

```
create or replace procedure p42 is
begin
    declare
        l_name all_tables.table_name%TYPE;
    begin
        select table_name
        into l_name        -- this reference is OK
        from all_tables
        where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES';
    end;

    select table_name
    into l_name            -- this reference errors
    from all_tables
    where table_name = 'JOBS';
end;
/

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

show errors

Errors for PROCEDURE P42:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
12/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/7     PLS-00201: identifier 'L_NAME' must be declared
14/2     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Notice that the error is reported against line 13, which is in the outer block; it doesn't complain about it in the inner block because it is in-scope there.

So, you need to declare the variable at the appropriate level. As Colin 't Hart says that is probably right at the top, between the `IS` and the first `BEGIN`, as that is the procedure-level `DECLARE` section (it doesn't need an explicit `DECLARE` keyword).